# VW Golf wont move in first but is fine in other gears?

Tags: vw, golf

My 08 plate Golf has literally just developed this problem, no other signs previous to now.

I'm going to take it to the garage in the morning but in the meantime am curious as to what might be causing the issue?

Symptoms:

- It'll move into first gear way too easily when the clutch is pressed, literally no resistance at all
- Once in first gear I can apply revs but as I release the clutch the car doesn't move and eventually stalls
- I can get the car into second gear some of the time but have to be very rough with it as it feels like 2nd gear is misaligned / blocked somehow?
- I can set off / drive as usual in 2nd gear (once I manage to get into second gear)
- All other gears feel and drive normally

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!